# java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s) - Spring

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbc

Why I am getting this exception from below code?

```
List<String> getId=jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select Id from MYTable", String.class);
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("sName", "AC");
parameters.addValue("ids", getId);
List<MypojoClass> result = new ArrayList<>();
String query ="select CTime,HTime from MYTable where Type=:sName and Id in((:ids)) and CTime > CONVERT_TZ(date_format(now() - interval 1 month,'%Y-%m-01 00:00:01'),'+00:00', '-05:30');";
result = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(query, parameters, ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(MypojoClass.class));
```

Exception :

```
 org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException) org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
    PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [
    select CTime,HTime from MYTable where Type=? and Id in((?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) and CTime > CONVERT_TZ(date_format(now() - interval 1 month,'%Y-%m-01 00:00:01'),'+00:00', '-05:30');]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove extra parentheses from `IN`

```
SELECT
    CTime,
    HTime
FROM
    MYTable
WHERE
    Type =?
AND Id IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
AND CTime > CONVERT_TZ(date_format(now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01 00:00:01' ),'+00:00','-05:30');
```

**Note:**

`SELECT '1' IN ('2','1','3');  Result: 1(TRUE)` [**See demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/68640/1)

`SELECT '1' IN (('2','1','3')); Result: [Err] 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)` [**See demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/68638)

`SELECT ('2','1','3') IN (('2','1','3'));  Result: 1(TRUE)` [**See demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/68639/1)